La lectura de datos no se esta realizando de manera correcta
El código que he realizado es el siguiente:
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#include "funciones.h"
#define TAM_LINEA 120
void imprimirEncabezado(ofstream &archResultados){
    archResultados<<setw(60)<< "EMPRESA DE OPINION DE MERCADO S. A."<<endl;
    imprimirSimbolo(archResultados,TAM_LINEA,'=');
    archResultados<<setw(52)<< "REGISTRO DE PREFERENCIAS DE LOS TELEVIDENTES"<<endl;
    imprimirSimbolo(archResultados,TAM_LINEA,'=');
    archResultados<<"DNI No."<<setw(12)<<"NOMBRE"<<setw(30)<<"SEXO"<<setw(15)<<"COMPANIA"<<setw(12)<<"CANAL"
            <<setw(17)<<"RANGO"<<endl;
   imprimirSimbolo(archResultados,TAM_LINEA,'-');
}
void imprimirSimbolo(ofstream &archResultados,int cantcar,char carRep){
    for(int i=1;i<=cantcar;i++){
        archResultados<<carRep;
    }
    archResultados<<endl;
}

void Leerdatos(ifstream &archTele, ofstream &archResultados){
   int  dni,compania,dd,mm,aa;
    imprimirEncabezado(archResultados);
    char sexo,car;
    while(true){
        archTele>>dni;
        if(archTele.eof()) break;
        archTele>>sexo;
        Leerletras(archTele,archResultados);
        archTele>>compania>>dd>>car>>mm>>car>>aa;
        imprimirResultados(archResultados,dni,sexo,aa,compania);
        archResultados<<endl;
        LeeryImprimirCanales(archTele,archResultados);
    }
}
void Leerletras(ifstream &archTele,ofstream &archResultados){
    char letra;
    archTele>>ws;
    while(true){
        letra = archTele.get();
        if( archTele.get( ) == '\n') break;
    }
}
void imprimirResultados(ofstream &archResultados,int dni,char sexo,int aa,char compania){
    archResultados<<dni;
    hallarSexo(archResultados,sexo);
    hallarCategoria(archResultados,aa);
    hallarCompania(archResultados,compania);
}
void hallarSexo(ofstream &archResultados,char sexo){
    
    if(sexo == 'F'){
        archResultados<<setw(20)<<"Femenino";
    }else{
        archResultados<<setw(20)<<"Masculino";
    }
}
void   hallarCategoria(ofstream &archResultados,int aa){
    if(aa > 2009){
        archResultados<<setw(12)<<"Menor";
    }
    else{
        if(aa>1988){
                 archResultados<<setw(12)<<"Joven";   
        }else{
                    archResultados<<setw(12)<<"Adulto";
        }
    }
}
void hallarCompania(ofstream &archResultados,char compania){
     
     if(compania == 'A'){
         archResultados<<setw(16)<<"TVPUCP";
     }
     else{
         if(compania == 'B'){
             archResultados<<setw(16)<<"CableMas";
         }else{
                     archResultados<<setw(16)<<"TPVision";
         }
     }
 }
void LeeryImprimirCanales(ifstream &archTele,ofstream &archResultados){
    int canal,hhI,mmI,ssI,hhF,mmF,ssF,hhD,mmD,ssD;
    char car;
    while(true){
        archTele>>canal;
         archTele>>hhI>>car>>mmI>>car>>ssI>>hhF>>car>>mmF>>car>>ssF;
        archResultados<<setw(50)<<canal<<setw(5)<<" "<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<hhI<<":"<<setw(2)<<mmI<<":"<<setw(2)<<ssI<<"-"
                <<setw(2)<<hhF<<":"<<setw(2)<<mmF<<":"<<setw(2)<<ssF<<setfill(' ');
        hallarDuracion(hhI,mmI,ssI,hhF,mmF,ssF,hhD,mmD,ssD);
        archResultados<<setw(5)<<" "<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<hhD<<":"<<setw(2)<<mmD<<":"<<setw(2)<<ssD<<setfill(' ')<<endl;
        if ( archTele.get() == '\n') break;
    }
}
void hallarDuracion(int hhI,int mmI,int ssI,int hhF,int mmF,int ssF,int &hhD,int &mmD,int &ssD){
    int inicio,fin,duracion;
    inicio=hhI*3600+mmI*60+ssI;
    fin=hhF*3600+mmF*60+ssF;
    duracion=fin-inicio;
    hhD=duracion/3600;
    mmD= (duracion%3600)/60;
    ssD= (duracion%3600)%60;
}

La impresión que me sale del código antes mencionado, es esta:
                             EMPRESA DE OPINION DE MERCADO S. A.
========================================================================================================================
            REGISTRO DE PREFERENCIAS DE LOS TELEVIDENTES
========================================================================================================================
DNI No.      NOMBRE                          SEXO       COMPANIA       CANAL            RANGO
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
69323674           Masculino       Menor        TPVision
                                                -1     00:101:6421788-1877610208:6421672:00     -139695:-10:-32
                                                -1     00:101:6421788-1877610208:6421672:00     -139695:-10:-32
                                                -1     00:101:6421788-1877610208:6421672:00     -139695:-10:-32
                                                -1     00:101:6421788-1877610208:6421672:00     -139695:-10:-32
                                                -1     00:101:6421788-1877610208:6421672:00     -139695:-10:-32
                                                -1     00:101:6421788-1877610208:6421672:00     -139695:-10:-32
                                                -1     00:101:6421788-1877610208:6421672:00     -139695:-10:-32
                                                -1     00:101:6421788-1877610208:6421672:00     -139695:-10:-32
                                                -1     00:101:6421788-1877610208:6421672:00     -139695:-10:-32
                                                -1     00:101:6421788-1877610208:6421672:00     -139695:-10:-32
                                                -1     00:101:6421788-1877610208:6421672:00     -139695:-10:-32
                                                -1     00:101:6421788-1877610208:6421672:00 

Y el archivo que estoy leyendo tiene estos datos:
69323674  M  ROSARIO_MENDOZA_EGUSQUIZA   B   31/03/2013    556     13:54:27   16:12:37
50981989   F  LORENA_IRMA_SALAZAR_CORRALES     C     9/08/1963   555   12:27:50  15:09:02   313   18:07:29   21:05:44
81521780   F  EDWARD_REYES_TANG   C   17/04/1988   772     20:44:39   21:50:11
80489052    F    FIORELLA_MARGOT_CERNA_PAIRAZAMAN  B  1/04/2012    551   18:49:35  20:09:37  311   21:37:21   23:30:55
45211033   F   ALONSO_FORZANI_CARO     B     4/08/2010  577     15:38:32     16:56:09
87179097  F  MADELEINE_SHIRAKAWA_MIRANDA     A     11/11/1988    551    10:31:37     12:18:19     701   14:26:06    16:35:54     557     20:15:32     22:09:03
99924579     F     MARIA_HELI_ARROYO_GORDILLO  A  21/09/2007  773    14:50:34  16:10:34     556  17:15:09    19:00:00     550  21:05:08  23:01:01
46702349   F  EMILIO_HERNANDEZ_BARRIOS    C    12/08/2005  312  13:41:24  15:27:02
23538843  M  JANET_REBECA_VEGA_GARCIA  A  16/01/2013     577   16:42:10    18:30:18
77017851     F     ANGEL_SHIRAKAWA_ORTEGA   C   17/02/2000   550     10:53:35     13:37:36   705  20:12:08     22:06:12
61214249   M  MADELEINE_WONG_MARTEL  C  29/12/2000    772    09:52:18     11:06:41   771     12:30:05    14:55:21   511    18:23:01     20:05:33    775   21:03:05    23:45:06
65959560  F   MAGALI_SILVANA_DIAZ_ANTEZANO  C  27/08/1972  701     09:58:10  12:24:42
38691712     M    BLANCA_MILAGROS_MEJIA_DIAZ    A    22/11/1990    310     14:38:28  17:00:43  577     18:45:21     19:30:21  771    21:01:01  23:45:18
81648037    F   ADRIA_GLORIA_RAFFO_CHUNG   A   9/10/1973    555  14:57:58  17:11:52   577   17:51:23  19:10:05   557   20:54:45  23:07:43
76255094  M   ROLANDO_CASTRO_SUAREZ    B    2/09/1959   775    11:03:16   12:34:08
54405508    F    GUILLERMO_ALFONSO_DELGADO_GONZALES  C  16/06/1978     772  20:26:00     23:24:49
28066659  M  EDGAR_RICHARD_PRADO_FALCON    B    17/03/1989     701     19:17:59  21:58:32
66571601     F  SILVANA_MALDONADO_RAMIREZ  A  10/01/1956   310  09:50:00  11:24:28  555     13:12:15  16:21:07  311  18:45:33  21:02:08
35369787  F  CESAR_BRUNO_PISCOYA_BRAVO  A  3/07/1996    555  09:53:16     11:58:03
30195706  F  JOSE_ROLANDO_CERNA_HIJAR    B    29/04/1955  553   16:44:33    18:48:59
54538509     F     ERICKA_VICTORIA_JUSTINO_FORZANI   B   29/03/1965  312     09:10:12    11:45:26
34782234   F    ELIZABETH_ELIZABETH_FERNANDEZ_ORTEGA     A     25/06/1972   550  14:43:12  17:37:22
84254975   F  TATIANA_NANCY_VILLA_YALLICO     C     25/04/2010     550     10:12:31    12:17:21   553  13:56:09     15:22:01   772     18:02:45    19:43:12   701     21:00:00  23:00:00

No se como solucionar el problema, por favor ayudenme.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Y cual seria el problema?

Después de ver el código, creo que el problema radica en la lectura y extracción de datos del archivo de texto.

Sexo: Para leer el sexo correctamente, debes usar archTele.get() para obtener un solo carácter y almacenarlo en la variable sexo. Luego, ignora el espacio en blanco con archTele.ignore().

Fecha: Para leer la fecha correctamente, debes separarla en partes usando >>. Por ejemplo:


int dia, mes, anio;
archTele >> dia >> car >> mes >> car >> anio;


Canales y horarios: Para leer los canales y sus horarios correctamente, necesitas un bucle que itere mientras haya datos en el archivo. Dentro del bucle, lee cada campo (canal, hora inicio, hora final) y utiliza las funciones hallarDuracion() e imprimirResultados() para procesar y mostrar la información correctamente.

Formato: Para mejorar el formato de salida, utiliza setw() para establecer el ancho de las columnas y setfill() para controlar el relleno de espacios en blanco.

Repetición: Elimina la repetición de información dentro del bucle que lee los canales y horarios. Solo imprime la información una vez por cada registro.


Eso fueron los errores que puede identificar.
Si necesitas más información, recomiendo revisar detenidamente el código, especialmente las funciones Leerdatos(), Leerletras(), LeeryImprimirCanales() y la sección de impresión de resultados en imprimirResultados().
Espero haberte ayudado
